# vue router's router-link in google maps infowindow

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, infowindow, vue-router

I've got this working fine, except that I've would like instead of `<a>` tag to use `<router-link>` tag because of `<a>` tag unlike `<router-link>` (which intercepts click event and don't reload the page) reloads a page.

```
const contentString = `
    <div class="popup">
        <a href="/places/${place._id}">
            <img src="..." />
            <h5>${place.name}</h5>
            <p>${place.gmap.address}</p>
        </a>
    </div>`

const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
infoWindow.setContent(contentString)
```

If I replace `<a>` tag for `<router-link>` it doesn't render to `<a>` tag as it would if that `<router-link>` was in vuejs template.

Comment: Would you please give a fiddle, or at least paste the code snippet related to vue? It is difficult to find the reason why a tag wasn't rendered with the information you provide now.

Comment: [Link to gist GoogleMaps.vue](https://gist.github.com/ridjis/5c4e40897b261bc949fca0ff300614e0)
That's pretty much about it. Vue component is too simple, the only problem as I can see would be with Google's API which accepts a string and renders it, I think it has nothing to do with vue, but somehow I'm wondering if Vue has the way to overcome that limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. `router-link` wasn't rendered because Vue.js got no chance to render it. You can let vue.js render your template at first, get rendered result as string by using `innerHTML`, and then pass the string to Google Maps API(`setContent`).

I'd like to provide 2 solutions here.

1. The first one is easy to read and understand. Just use it as a normal component, but add `v-show="false"` in the tag so that it won't appear in your view. (`place` can be passed as a prop)

   ```
   <div id="app">
     <api v-show="false" :place="place"></api>
   </div>
   ```

   Vue instance:

   ```
   new Vue({
     router: new VueRouter({}),
     el: '#app',
     data: {
       place: {
         id: 1,
         name: 'awesome-name',
         address: 'somewhere',
       }
     },
     components: {
       api: {
         props: [ 'place' ],
         template: `
           <div class="api">
           <div class="popup">
             <router-link :to="'/places/' + place.id">
               <h5>{{place.name}}</h5>
               <p>{{place.address}}</p>          
             </router-link>
           </div>
           </div>
         `,
       },
     },
     mounted() {
       console.log(this.$children[0].$el.innerHTML);
       //=> <div class="popup"><a href="#/places/1" class=""><h5>awesome-name</h5> <p>somewhere</p></a></div>
     },
   });
   ```
2. If you don't want to pollute your html, you can generate the component's vm programmatically by using `Vue.extend`, create a virtual dom, then mount your vm to created dom.

   ```
   const myComp = Vue.extend({
     router: this.$options.router,
     template: `
       <div class="api">
       <div class="popup">
         <router-link to="/places/${this.place.id}">
           <h5>${this.place.name}</h5>
           <p>${this.place.address}</p>          
         </router-link>
       </div>
       </div>
     `,
   });
   const comp = new myComp().$mount(document.createElement('div'));
   console.log(comp.$el.innerHTML);
   //=> <div class="popup"><a href="#/places/1" class=""><h5>awesome-name</h5> <p>somewhere</p></a></div>
   ```

I combined solutions above in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/qq05b9av/1/), please have a look.

Comment: I'm using single file components with the runtime-only build so the 2nd solution isn't possible to achieve. How to extend vue component in a runtime-only compiler, is it possible?

Comment: @ridjis Yes. since vue-loader is able to convert templates in SFCs into render functions, you can just define the component(`api` in my example) as a SFC.